# Force Reload of Background Page From Popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension that on occasion borks the background.js page. I can listen for an event from the popup that calls:

document.location.reload()

Which works to reload background.js.

However, if things bork hard enough, then the listener isn't available and I'm stuck. I'd like to put a "When all else fails push this button" message in my popup that would blow out and refresh the background.html and background.js pages.

Anyone know how to do that in a Chrome Extension?

Comment: `chrome.runtime.restart()`

Comment: Looks like that only works in kiosk mode. However, chrome.runtime.reloadI() shows some promise. Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: Is there a way to call that against a background page from the popup? If I have to call it in the context of the background page but JS is borked I don't know how to execute the command.

Comment: Register a message handler in your background script with `chrome.runtime.onMessage` then use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send a message to the handler. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage

Comment: Thanks @holmberd the problem I have is that if JS has died in the background page the handler no longer responds. Or would the runtime API get around that problem somehow?

Comment: If you have registered the onMessage event when the background page is initiated, then it will wake up the background script if you are running `persistent: false`. If your background script is set to always run, you will need to check your code that the onMessage event is called correctly.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.reload()` works directly from a popup. You don't need to call it from background. It will reload the whole extension.

Comment: Thanks @Deliaz Totally right!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Deliaz in the comments:

**chrome.runtime.reload()**

can be called from the popup to reload the entire extension.

While that also closes the popup when called, it is the best solution I could find to force refresh background.js after JS had died.